# Proving homotopy is equivalence relation in HoTT

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

So, this is maybe just details, just had some questions on how to correctly write the proofs. In the HoTT book lemma 2.4.2 says that homotopy is an equivalence relation on each dependent function type $\prod_{x:A} P(x)$, which means provide elements for the types:

$$\prod_{f:\prod_{x:A} P(x)} (f\sim f)$$
$$\prod_{f,g:\prod_{x:A} P(x)} (f\sim g) \to (g \sim f)$$
$$\prod_{f,g,h:\prod_{x:A} P(x)} (f\sim g) \to (g \sim h) \to (f\sim h)$$

For the first one, it is definitionally equal to the type $$\prod_{f:\prod_{x:A} P(x)} \prod_{x:A} (f(x)=f(x))$$
so given f and x as above, $refl_{f(x)} : f(x)=_{P(x)}f(x)$.

Now the second is the same as:
$$\prod_{f,g:\prod_{x:A} P(x)} ( \prod_{x:A}(f(x)=g(x)) )\to( \prod_{x:A} (g(x)=f(x)))$$
My question is, can i say that this is the same as
$$\prod_{f,g:\prod_{x:A} P(x)}  \prod_{x:A}(f(x)=g(x)) \to (g(x)=f(x))$$
which can be proven by calling Lemma 2.1.1, or we're not allowed to do that (factor out the $\prod_{x:A}$)? Intuitively i think we should be able to. Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pull out the $\prod\limits_{x:A}$ at all. The term you desire is:
$$\lambda f,g : \prod_{x : A} P(x).\ \lambda p : \prod_{x : A} f(x)=g(x).\ \lambda x : A.\ p(x)^{-1}$$
More intuitively, the $\prod\limits_{x:A} f(x)=g(x)$ before the arrow gives you for each $x : A$ a path $p(x)$ from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$. To obtain a term of type $\prod\limits_{x:A} g(x)=f(x)$, simply take the same path in the opposite direction for each $x$, i.e. take $\lambda x : A.\ p(x)^{-1}$.